# CardLayout IllegalArgumentException with next()

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, illegalargumentexception, cardlayout

I am attempting to create a program that moves from panel to panel and in each panel the user answers a question. I am currently trying to use next() to switch cards, but it gives me an IllegalArgumentException problem.

I have simplified my code into the basis of my problem in order to get code unnecessary for the problem out of the way.
My main class is arrow, and my second class is Flash, since I will hopefully have each panel be its own physical file. I am attempting to call the same next() function in Flash with the same effect even though there technically isn't a third panel.

Here is Arrow (Main)

```
package layout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Arrow{
public JPanel panelHouse;
public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
public int total = 3000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Arrow window = new Arrow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } } }); } //putting all the closing brackets on one line saves space. This is test code so it doesn't matter to me
public Arrow() {
    initialize();
}
public Arrow(int x){
    //this is here so I don't run initialize when I need to create an Arrow variable in other classes
    //it doesn't actually do anything
}

private void initialize() {
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout(0, 0);
    frame.setBounds(400, 400, 909, 572);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(cl);

    JPanel panelHouse = new JPanel();
    panelHouse.setBounds(0, 0, 10, 10);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelHouse, "Housing");
    panelHouse.setLayout(null);

    Flash Flash1 = new Flash();
    frame.getContentPane().add(Flash1, "Flash");
    Flash1.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnHouseNext = new JButton("NEXT STATION");
    btnHouseNext.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    btnHouseNext.setBounds(344, 371, 184, 48);
    btnHouseNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { 
            cl.next(frame);
        }
    });//Close housingNext button actionlistener
    panelHouse.add(btnHouseNext);
}//close initialize

public JPanel getPanelHouse() {
    return panelHouse;
}

public JFrame getFrame(){
    return frame;
}
}//close class body
```

Here is Flash (second panel)

```
package layout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Flash extends JPanel{
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Flash() {
        Arrow a = new Arrow(4);
        JPanel Flash1 = new JPanel();
        setBounds(0, 0, 10, 10);
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.orange);

        JButton buttonFlash = new JButton("NEXT STATION");
        buttonFlash.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        buttonFlash.setBounds(344, 371, 184, 48);
        buttonFlash.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Flash1.setVisible(false);
            cardLayout.next(a.getFrame());
            }
        });
        add(buttonFlash);
        setVisible(true);
        }   
}
```

Here is my error stack trace

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout
at java.awt.CardLayout.checkLayout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.CardLayout.next(Unknown Source)
at layout.Arrow$2.actionPerformed(Arrow.java:48)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Now I have also seen code that had the container be a JPanel instead of a JFrame like I do. Am I doing it incorrectly and should change mine?

EDIT: I changed my code to reflect the advice

Comment: The `CardLayout` in the `Flash` class has no relationship to the parent container or the layout it's using, I'd even argue that it has no responsibility making decisions about what should happen next, it should be communicating that back to the parent, preferably via some kind of `interface`

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace this line:

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
```

With this:

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(cl);
```

The way it currently is written, you are setting the layout of the frame to a brand new CardLayout, instead of using the one that you created and assigned to the `cl` variable.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same error at the same line. Thank you for the tip though.

Comment: @Josh: he's on the money, you are creating **three** CardLayout instances, when you should only be using one, the same one. This is nothing but OOPs common sense. A new reference to a class is a new and distinct reference.

Comment: @Josh: look further in your code. Anywhere you see `new CardLayout()` **get rid of it**, except for the original one.

Comment: @Hover Let me preface by saying I apologize for being dense and I edited my code to reflect my current progress. Do you mean that I shouldn't run setLayout for panelHouse or for the flash panel? Or are you referring to when I create a null cardlayout in the Flash class in order to run the next() function. I only create a new CardLayout once (or so I thought).

Comment: @Josh: No, I'm not saying that at all. It's simply a matter that you're creating at least 3 CardLayout instances and treating them as if they're all the same one, it's as simple as that. Only create one instance. Regarding: `" I only create a new CardLayout once."` -- the hell you do. Again, simply search this page on the terms `new CardLayout` -- tell me how many times you see this in your code??

Comment: @Josh: now you're changing your code, and have gotten rid of one of the instances but still have one more. Again, this is very basic Java, and you shouldn't be doing Swing if you don't understand the concept of instances.

Comment: @Josh: your error again is here `cardLayout.next(a.getFrame());`. That's not the right CardLayout instance. Use the one that is held by the `a` (terrible variable name) instance.

Comment: e.g. perhaps, `((CardLayout) a.getFrame().getLayout).next(a.getFrame());`

Comment: @Hover Yes I acknowledge that I call new CardLayout twice, once in Arrow and once in Flash. I do so in Flash in order so that I can call next and thus flip to the next card. And to answer your last question, I have only learned swing through youtube videos and helpful (I swear I'm not being sarcastic) individuals such as yourself on stack overflow eventually beating concepts into my head.

Comment: @Josh: again I'm telling you that you can't do this, that it makes no sense to create a totally new CardLayout and use it in place of the original. I don't know how to spell this any simpler, but to solve this, get rid of the `new CardLayout()` call in the Flash class, and use the CardLayout created in the first class within the Flash class. The easiest way to do this is give the Arrow class a `next()` method that calls `next(...)` on its own CardLayout instance, the one being used as a layout, and then call that public method where needed.

Comment: @Josh: and again, this has nothing to do with Swing and all to do with basic object-oriented concepts. If you create two JFrames, one you display and one you don't, calling methods on the 2nd non displayed JFrame will have no effect on the first one. Same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating too many CardLayout instances when you only need one. Suggestions:

- Make CardLayout a field of the class that is using it
- Give that same class a public method, say called `public void next()` where you use the CardLayout to swap JPanels.
- Call that method where needed.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Flash extends JPanel {
    private Arrow arrow = new Arrow();

    public Flash() {
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(new JButton(new NextAction("Next")));            

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(arrow, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class NextAction extends AbstractAction {
        public NextAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            arrow.next();  // *** call arrow's public next method that you created

            // no need to make a new CardLayout instance
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Flash mainPanel = new Flash();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleCardLayout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
class Arrow extends JPanel {
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout(); // make me a field
    private JPanel cardHolder = new JPanel(cardLayout);

    public Arrow() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            cardHolder.add(createCard(i), "card " + i);
        }

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(cardHolder, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    // public method that other objects can call
    public void next() {
        cardLayout.next(cardHolder);  // call next on the correct object
    }

    // simply creates a "pretty" new JPanel
    private JComponent createCard(int i) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Card " + i);
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 50f));

        float h = (float)Math.random();
        Color c = Color.getHSBColor(h, 1f, 1f);
        label.setForeground(c.darker());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(label);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(c.darker(), 20));
        panel.setBackground(c.brighter().brighter());

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        return panel;
    }
}
```